# Wordpress using add action 'the content' deletes all pages content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using:

```
add_action('the_content' , 'statistics_page');
```

And in the function 'statistics_page' I put:

```
if(is_page(25)) { //blabla }
```

This perfectly works on the page I want it displayed on (25) but all other pages have their content stripped, they don't display anything.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT: extra info**

Website link: http://pauldekoning.com/wot
Youll see that Home doesnt display text, nor does the forum page have a forum.
Only the statistic page displays something.

Comment: Have you tried to add else statement for all pages that aren`t page 25?

Comment: I dont know what I have to use as else then. I dont want all other pages to display 1 thing. If you look back at my post I will have added my website link. I want my Home and Forum page to still display certain stuff made by other plugins (forum by forum plugin, Home just being a static page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_content` is a filter so you should you `apply_filter` instead of `add_action` and you've to make sure you return the actual content from the function. Try after updating your code to following.

```
apply_filters('the_content' , 'statistics_page');

function statistics_page($content){

    if(  is_page(25) ) { 
        //blabla 
    }

    return $content;

}
```

Comment: I get the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filter() in /var/customers/webs/ni667144_1/wot/wp-content/plugins/brogin/bro_statistics.php on line 3 , any reason why?

Comment: There was a typo, it should be `apply_filters`. Updated the answer.